# Accepted answer not at top

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

[In my recent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137989/how-do-i-minimise-waste-on-a-flight) I got a lot of answers that gave relevant information, but didn't answer the actual question asked.

I collated the useful information from those answers, made it a community wiki and accepted the answer so that it would be displayed at the top, so it would be useful to those who are interested in the actual answer.

For some reason it *isn't* displayed at the top, even though it is the accepted answer (it's currently languishing in 14th place out of 15).

Why is this the case?
(I'm not sure that it's a bug, but it seemed the most relevant of the required tags)

Comment: valid query, I'm not sure I know the answer either.  Will await a SE response.

Comment: I wonder whether this might get a better answer if posted on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @mdewey Thanks, I'll try it there as well

Answer (score 5):

This is the exceptional case for *accepted self-answer*.

Accepted self-answer will lose its acceptance priority and will be ordered just like any other answers.

From the Help Center, [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> If you accept:
>
> - [...]
> - **your own answer**: No reputation is awarded, and the answer does not float to the top of the list. You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.
> - [...]

Comment: This is slightly different though, the question is a community wiki

Comment: @Phill doesn't matter since the answer is still posted by the OP.